# How to compare two columns from one datatable with two other column in another datatable..?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, datatable, bigdata

I am right now working in a project that deals with big data. We get huge data from client say some 6 million data and we process that to align them and fill the null spaces and produce that as end result.

However there is a need to check we are not losing any data or mixing up data in the process.

> So the story comes like in a datatable say Table 1 i have two columns
>   named part and client. and this i want to compare with the processed
>   datatable say Table 2 with the columns newpart and new clients. here
>   the data is not mandatory to be in same order and also the Table 2
>   will have additional columns added.

**The question here is How can i compare these 6 million data to maximum accuracy ? is there any open source tool to do this. ? any reference video or journal ?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the combination of `part` and `client` is unique in each table?  I am also assuming you have a primary our unique index on `(part, client)` on each table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t ( PRIMARY KEY(part, client) )
    SELECT part, client FROM table1;
INSERT INTO t
    SELECT part, client FROM table2;
```

You now have a list of all part-client pairs across both tables.

This will find the ones missing from table1:

```
SELECT part, client
    FROM t
    LEFT JOIN table1  USING(part, client)
    WHERE part IS NULL
```

There are variants on this, but the likely key is `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks Ric. This will be helpful. I will try out. Since we are looking it through a black box testing mind, i thought a tool to help out check these data will make the effort less. Anyways i really thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Check out Percona Toolkit -- it may have utilities that will help you.